# Identify Icom portable radio

Tags: icom

I'm trying to identify this Icom portable radio.
Unfortunately, the picture is in a quite a bad shape.

Does someone know the model number?

[image: Icom radio]

Thank you!

Comment: The Icom America Headquarters Office is five minutes from my house -- actually, probably 3 minutes.  They have a display, sort of like a museum of old rigs, in their main lobby and I know they have old radios going back 30 years plus.  They may have something that looks like this.  Unfortunately, this is Sunday and tomorrow I am away for most of the day.  But, I will try and get over there and look if someone else does not answer first.  Their location:  Kirkland, Washington.

Comment: It could be an ancestor of the IC-V80 line of HTs.

Comment: It looks similar to an IC-V8.

Comment: The 4 buttons (P1-P4) make me think it's a land mobile radio. It could be the Icom F1000 or F3230 except the antenna's on the wrong side.

Comment: The Icom IC-F3 (amateur radio) HT also has P1 - P4 buttons as shown in the OP's post but it also has two up/down buttons just to the left of the screen.  And, the OP's image post shows some shadowy buttons to the left of the screen on careful inspection.

Answer (score 8):

I went to the Icom America Headquarters office in Kirkland to look over the wall of history of a sampling of their amateur radio gear.  This model shown below in the photo is the closest in appearance to the photo posted by the OP.  It is an Icom IC-F3, first released in 1997.

[image: Icom IC-F3]

The OP's image of the HT appears to be a derivative of the IC-F3 called the IC-F3GS.  Here is an image of the IC-F3GS.  It seems to have the right body shape as the OP's photo as well as the up/down arrow design.  Even though the up/down arrow buttons to the left of the screen are hard to make out, if you zoom in the OP's image you will be able to see the buttons.

[image: Icom IC-F3GS]